# Does Mono XSP Server Work?

Tags: mono, crash, xsp

I'm trying for a week to make my XSP server work with simple static content: html-pages, js-files, gifs, jpegs etc... No ASP.NET. And this server always randomly crashes while navigating this pages with browser. 
My Environment is: Mono 2.6.1, Windows Vista. I also tried to build XSP on linux (with Novell's make-files) but same result. 
So, could XSP be used anyhow? Is there anybody who made XSP work fine without crashes? If yes, please tell me how. If no, is there another open-source ASP.NET http-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try xsp2 not xsp, as it is newer.  Also Tomi is right and you should be using mod-mono for production, however, that is not going to work on Windows right now (at least the last thing I read was that mod_mono was not yet working with Apache on Windows).  XSP2 definately works on Linux, and although I haven't tried it on Windows, but if there are problems with it you should probably file a bug report with the Mono team.  Xsp definately does not work with some of the code I have written, so I think it is only used for Net 1.1 era asp, not asp2.0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately i tried both xsp and xsp2 from trunk and from some different branches and no result. There is already a ticket on Novel's bug tracker. I'm now using Cassini and waiting for stable xsp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example Apache with [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) or [Nginx](http://tomi.developmententity.sk/Blog/Post/1) on Linux. I wouldn't recommend using XSP for production use since it's used mostly as development web server in conjuction with MonoDevelop.

Comment: I've thought about it but some tests show bad performance of mod_mono and that it still is not stable... Did you hear something about it?

Comment: I don't know much about mod_mono since I'm using Nginx as production web server. I didn't tried any performance tests with it so far. Standalone Nginx is high performance web server but I dunno how is performance affected by mono fastcgi server which is used when you want to host ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC web apps with Nginx.